# Two-Dimensional Arrays issue. Hope for Assistance

Tags: java, arrays

I am using `Java` in `BlueJ` and I am fairly new to it. If there is one thing I'm not too good at in Java, it's arrays, let alone Two-Dimensional Arrays. Hopefully someone can assist me in this program as I feel somewhat overwhelmed and I'm not quite sure where to even begin.

The purpose of this program is to use a Two-Dimensional to tally up results of a political poll from a .TXT file.
The input file "PROG4IN.TXT" contains one line for each voter polled. Each line contains the name of the favored candidate and the age of the voter.
Using an array having two rows and three columns, I must tally the voters by favored candidate and age group; the three age groups are 18-29, 30-49, and 50-99.

This is what the desired final output is supposed to look like:

```
Candidate   18-29   30-49   50-99   Total
Krook          2       4       6      12
Leyer          3       3       2       8
```

For reference, this is what is in the "PROG4IN.TXT" file:

```
Krook   45
Leyer   40
Krook   76
Leyer   55
Krook   20
Krook   50
Leyer   28
Krook   30
Leyer   23
Krook   72
Krook   42
Krook   81
Leyer   64
Krook   52
Leyer   18
Leyer   34
Krook   60
Krook   26
Leyer   49
Krook   37
```

I must use this template:

```
public class Table {
    private int[][] table;
    private String[] names;

    public Table() {
        // Create the two-dimensional tally array "table"
        // having 2 rows and 3 columns.  Row 0 corresponds
        // to candidate Krook and row 1 to candidate Leyer.
        // The columns correspond to the three age groups
        // 18-29, 30-49, and 50-99.  Initialize all the
        // tallies to zero.  Create the array "names" to
        // hold the candidate names: names[0]="Krook" and
        // names[1]="Leyer".
    }

    public void tally(String name, int age) {
        // Add one to the tally in the "table" array that
        // corresponds to the name and age passed as arguments.
        // Hint: Use the equals method to determine whether
        // two strings are equal: name.equals("Krook") is
        // true when name is "Krook".
    }

    public void report() {
        // Use nested loops to print a report in the format
        // shown above.  Assume that the tallies have already
        // been made.
    }
}
```

After all that, however, I must create a main class that creates a Table object, tallies the data from PROG4IN.TXT, and prints the report.

I hope someone can assist me in this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your array will look like this:

```
table = new int[2][3]();
```

and inside it will be like this:

```
{
{count for 1st age group for krook, for 2nd age group for krook, last group for krook}
{count for 1st age group for leyer, for 2nd age group for leyer, last group for leyer}
}
```

So when you want to add to the middle age group for leyer, for example, you'd do table[1][1] += some amount.

Or for third age group for krook, youd do table[0][2]  += someamount.